# Outlook 2007: compose, and reply error with "Not Implemented."

Tags: windows, outlook-2007

This is happening on a Windows Vista machine with Office 2007 Ultimate.

I have run repair from the control panel and also the MS Office Diagnostic tool.  No problems are reported.

When I started Outlook my mail box opens and I can read my messages.  If I click compose or reply then Outlook gives me a dialog that says, "Not Implemented."  The rest of office seems to be working fine.

Does anyone know what causes this or the correct way to repair it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a [fairly common problem](http://www.google.ca/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=office+outlook+Not+Implemented&btnG=Search&meta=), and it appears to be update related.  Have you tried initiating the repair from the *installation media (DVD)* and not from Control Panel?

This seems to have worked for a lot of people.